# Finding Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> For the equation below, of Van der Waal form:
>   $$\left(P+\frac{n^{2}a}{V^{2}}\right)(V-nb)=nRT$$
>
> Determine the partial derivatives; $\Bigl(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\Bigr)_{P,n}    \text{and }  \Bigl(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\Bigr)_{T,n}$
>
> Where $a,b, n, R$ are constants.

This is what I've done so far for one of the partial derivatives. I dont know what else to do from here, sorry.
$$P=\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{n^{2}a}{V^{2}}$$

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}=-\frac{nRT}{(V-nb)^2}+\frac{2n^{2}a}{V^{3}}$$

Comment: Do you know how to take normal derivatives? Because a partial derivative is exactly a normal derivative except every variable is a constant except for the variable that you are taking the derivative to respect to. in the dP/dV case, V is the only variable that is not a constant...This is pretty much an issue of product rule (f = g/h, f' = ((h)(g') - (g)(h'))/h^2

Comment: @mathguy So would this be what you said? $P=\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-\frac{n^{2}a}{V^{2}}$
       
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}= \frac{nRT}{-nb}-\frac{n^{2}a}{2V}$$

Comment: No, I think you are taking that derivative wrong. I did it by hand and you should end up with what's on your question (the last expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find $\partial P / \partial T$ and $\partial P / \partial V$ such that: $$\frac{\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}}{\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}$$

I hope this will help you

Comment: Im still not sure anything else you can tell me?

Comment: You can see $P(V)$ as $\alpha\cdot(V-\beta)^{-1}-\gamma V^{-2}$ where $\alpha=nRT,\beta=nb,\gamma=n^2 a$ 
are constants so taking the derivative: 
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}=\frac{\partial}{\partial V}[\alpha\cdot(V-\beta)^{-1}]-\frac{\partial}{\partial V}[\gamma V^{-2}]$$
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}=(-1)\alpha\cdot(V-\beta)^{-2}-(-2)\gamma V^{-3}=-\frac{\alpha}{(V-\beta)^2} + \frac{2\gamma}{V^3}
=-\frac{nRT}{(V-nb)^2} + \frac{2n^2 a}{V^3}$$  

You can do the same for $P(T)$